# Fdisk partitions in fabric script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04, fabric, ubuntu-server

In the hard disk partitions, I used fdisk module. In the fdisk module, it is asking some command line inputs like below.

`Command (m for help): p`

I need to run this module on 16 servers.So I am using fabric script to run this on the 16 servers. But every time it is asking the input commands.

Is there any option in the fabric module to give standard commands.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is just a matter of figuring out the fdisk commands you need and then creating a bash script out of them.  There are four options [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/258152/fdisk-partition-in-single-line).  Pick one of them and then fabricify it--e.g.,:

```
sudo('apt-get update')
sudo('apt-get install parted')
sudo('parted -a optimal /dev/usb mkpart primary 0% 4096MB')
```

Replace `/dev/usb` with your disk.  You'll also have to add a mount and add the entry to fstab.

Comment: Thanks, @2ps we will check it.